# Unable to install saml in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My system environment is WAMP 2.5,

How to install `laravel5-saml(SSO)` ?

As per readme suggestion,

1. Added the " "aacotroneo/laravel-saml2": "*" " in composer.json file
2. Executed this " composer update " in the command line (NO ERROR)
3. C:\wamp\www\myproject\config.php
   Added :  'Aacotroneo\Saml2\Saml2ServiceProvider', 
   in the **provider** array

   Added :  'Saml2'     => 'Aacotroneo\Saml2\Facades\Saml2Auth',
   in the **alias** array
4. Got below error

> bash-3.1$ composer update
>
> Loading composer repositories with package
>   information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Nothing to
>   install or update Generating autoload files Generating optimized class
>   loader bash-3.1$ php artisan vendor:publish
>
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]   Class
>   'Aacotroneo\Saml2\Saml2ServiceProvider' not found

How to resolve the above problem?

Comment: Hi @Marcin Nabiałek you have any idea to fix this problem.

Comment: Are you using Laravel 5 or 5.1?

Comment: "laravel/framework": "5.1.*"

Comment: That's likely your issue.  When I added the same package to my composer.json file, when i ran `composer update` it didn't actually install anything.  Worked fine on my 5.0 project however.

Comment: working on 5.0, but failed in 5.1

Comment: The package aacotroneo/laravel-saml2 works in laravel 5.0 and laravel 5.2 but not in 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package aacotroneo/laravel-saml2 works in laravel 5.0 and laravel 5.2 but not in 5.1

See https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2/pull/16